# selector last element wrapped by parent

Tags: css-selectors

I am trying to access the last `.icon` element in the DOM.  I have tried .icon:last-of-type or .icon:last-child, but it does not work. Do not use .wrap:last-child because it has many .wrap below it does not have .icon.  I want to change the color of the last icon.  For example:

```
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="icon">0000000</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="icon">0000000</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="icon">0000000</div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="other-icon">0000000</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I can change the color of "0000000" text by using following CSS:

```css
 div.wrap:last-child div.item div.icon {
  color: green;
 }
```

```html
 <div class="wrap">
   <div class="item">
  <div class="icon">0000000</div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="wrap">
   <div class="item">
  <div class="icon">0000000</div>
   </div>
 </div>
 <div class="wrap">
   <div class="item">
  <div class="icon">0000022</div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: I just want to change the color of the last .icon

Comment: i just update the question, check it plz "Do not use .wrap:last-child because it has many .wrap below it does not have .icon.".